# Can I show a custom Local notification View or an Custom Alert view when app is in Background?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Actually I want to show a local notification in my app. But i want to show this notification with some custom design like ok and cancel button on it and image also. Alert view also can work but i am not sure if i can show it when app is in background Please suggest some solution.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the view of `Local Notification` when it fires and when your app is in background, till in `iOS 7`. May be in `iOS 8` you can do this.

Also if you want to use the `UIAlertView` to show the Notification, you can only show it when the app is in foreground.

You have to use this function in `AppDelegate.m` file to get the notification when app is in foreground.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```